Libre image/video annotation software?
I am in need of software to empower users to easily annotate images and video with boxes, lines, points, etc., and export these annotations in some industry standard format.
It is important that the software be currently maintained, open-source, liberally licensed, and maintained/governed by an organization that isn't profit-seeking.  CVAT would have been a good choice when it was maintained by OpenCV, but it has somehow been co-opted by a for-profit that is paywalling new features.
Any recommendations for well-supported software to support image annotation workflows?

Annotating images sounds simple. You just draw on the image. Or what do you mean by "annotate"? If the annotation is separate from the image, what should the annotation do if the image changes (e.g. cut the size in half)?

Do you happen to know an industry standard?

What OS do you need the program for? Windows, Linux, Mac?

@ThomasWeller COCO format is extremely common.  It stores the annotations separately, and there are lots of libraries in many languages to load the annotations separately from the image, but then combine them (for display, for further annotation, for image processing algorithms).  OS: Cross-platform preferred - Windows definitely, Linux and Mac hopefully.

~0% chance for anything like that being open source. Video editing support is not easy considering all the various formats. Even free video editors are either closed source or don't support various kinds of permament annotating too "easily", yet alone temporary one, which is non-standard. It'd need to be some kind of overlayer + player maybe, but can't see anything like that.

@Destroy666 would much prefer if the annotations were stored not in the video, e.g. in a JSON file.  I don't need to support arbitrary video formats, just one is probably fine.  In this sense I don't need to edit the video, so much as simply display it in a convenient way that allows the user to draw some labeled boxes on a canvas overlaying the frame, then save those labeled boxes in a JSON or CSV with time, xy-coords, label.
